# How to get Specific user choice in multiple array in php post

Tags: php

Am creating a quiz for a school.
Everything is working fine
I have a questions on display like:

- Who is the richest man in the world?
- A. Bill Gates
- B. Joseph Bezos
- C. Alan Cash
- D. Christiano Ronaldo
- Which football club has won the UEFA champions league for 3
  consecutive times?
- A. Barcelona
- B. Real Madrid
- C. Chelsea
- D. Juventus

My problem is when a user make a choice I want to get the user's choice in the next page (called proccess.php) using post.

Like

- Who is the richest man in the world?
- User's choice: **Alan Cash**
- Which football club has won the UEFA champions league for 3
  consecutive times?
- User's choice: **Barcelona**

But am getting:

- Who is the richest man in the world?
- User's choice: **Alan Cash** **Barcelona**
- Which football club has won the UEFA champions league for 3
  consecutive times?
- User's choice: **Alan Cash**  **Barcelona**

This is the code that displays the questions (working fine)

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">



     <?php
        foreach($questions as $id => $question) {
            echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";
            echo "<ol><li><h5 style='font-weight:bolder'>  $question</h5>"."</li><ol>";//display the question

            //Display multiple choices
            $randomChoices = $choices[$id];
            $randomChoices = shuffle_assoc($randomChoices);
            foreach ($randomChoices as $key => $values){
                echo '<li style="list-style-type: upper-alpha; font-weight:bolder;"><input required="" type="radio" name="response['.$id.']" id="'.$id.'" value="' .$values.'"/>';
            ?>
                <label for="question-<?php echo($id); ?>"><?php echo($values);?></label></li>
        <?php

            }
                echo("</ul>");
                echo("</div>");
            }
           ?>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Quiz" />
    </form>
```

This is the process.php code.
It displays all the user choices for all questions under a given question.

```
<?php
    foreach($questions as $id => $question) {
        echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";
        echo "<h5 style='font-weight:bolder'> $question</h5>"."<ol>";//display the question




            echo '<li style="list-style-type: upper-alpha; font-weight:bolder;">';
        //display user choice 
        ?>

            <label for="question-<?php echo($id); ?>"><?php   foreach($_POST['response'] as $key => $value){
       echo $value;}
       }

  ?></label></li>
    <?php


            echo("</ul>");
            echo("</div>");

        }
       ?>
```

My questions is how do I get the process.php display one user choice per question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your form, you have...

```
<input required="" type="radio" name="response['.$id.']" id="'.$id.'" value="' .$values.'"/>
```

So each input has the `$id` which is the questions ID as the index to the response (`response['.$id.']`).  But in your process.php you loop over all of the responses every time...

```
foreach($_POST['response'] as $key => $value){
       echo $value;}
```

If you just want the response for the particular question, you need to pick out the response for the particular question you are currently displaying the answer for...

```
echo $_POST['response'][$id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, your approach is correct, just not echoing the values properly, add a "br" tag to move the next element to the next line, try

```
 echo $value . "<br>";
```